# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that compares the density of a certain mass and volume to a list of densities of compounds, and return the type of compound I am analyzing.

This is the part of the code that is returning an error:

```
peso = float(input("Qual o peso do plastico da sua protese?"))
volume = float(input("Qual o volume do material?"))
str(peso)
str(volume)

def resultados():
  print('O peso do plastico é de ' + peso, end="", flush=True)

resultados()
  print(' g e tem um volume de ' + volume + "dm^3")
```

The error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d36344c01741> in <module>()
      8     print('O peso do plastico é de ' + peso, end="", flush=True)
      9 
---> 10 resultados()
     11 print(' g e tem um volume de ' + volume + "dm^3")
     12 #############

<ipython-input-9-d36344c01741> in resultados()
      6 
      7 def resultados():
----> 8     print('O peso do plastico é de ' + peso, end="", flush=True)
      9 
     10 resultados()

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: `str` does not modify the variable. You need to reassign it, i.e. `peso = str(peso)`, etc

Comment: Also, I just realised that it might be better if you do not directly use `float()` around input like that. You could leave it as is, then check on the next line if it is indeed a float using something like `while not(isinstance(peso, float)): peso = input("This is not a number! What is the mass? ")` and only after that convert to float to do calculations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have some options about how to go about this

Using `peso = str(peso)` and same for `volume = str(volume)`

```
peso = float(input("Qual o peso do plastico da sua protese?"))
volume = float(input("Qual o volume do material?"))
peso = str(peso)
volume = str(volume)

def resultados():
  print('O peso do plastico é de ' + peso, end="", flush=True)

resultados()
print(' g e tem um volume de ' + volume + "dm^3")
```

Or you could just convert them to `str` when you are performing your `print` this way you can preserve the values as `floats` if you want to do more calculations and not have to convert them back and forth over and over

```
peso = float(input("Qual o peso do plastico da sua protese?"))
volume = float(input("Qual o volume do material?"))

def resultados():
  print('O peso do plastico é de ' + str(peso), end="", flush=True)

resultados()
print(' g e tem um volume de ' + str(volume) + "dm^3")
```

Comment: I'm doing this, still get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

You have to assign the cast to the variable. Only`str(peso)` doesn't modify it. Because `str()` returns a `str type`. So, you need to do that:

```
peso = str(peso)
```

Comment: I'm doing this, still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Use formatted string

```
str_val = "Hello"
int_val = 1234
msg = f'String and integer concatenation : {str_val} {int_val}'
```

Output

```
String and integer concatenation : Hello 1234
```

Comment: float, not int, this still doesn't work.