# Conditionally Add a Number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe that looks like this:

```
  ID     FirstNumberHour     NewFirst     LastNumberHour     NewLast
  1        7.0                7a           4.0               4p
  2        2.0                2a           10.0             10p
  3        4.0                4p           11.0             11p
```

The `FirstNumberHour` variable was created from the `NewFirst` variable through the code:

```
DF['FirstNumberHourUpdate'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['NewLast']+['m'], format='%H%p').dt.hour
```

To convert the `NewFirst` and `NewLast` to a 24-hour time variable, I want to conditionally add 12 to the times where its counterpart `First/LastNumberHour` has a "p". The NEW variables are objects and the `First/LastNumberHour` are float64. So for example the output table would look like this:

```
  ID     FirstNumberHourUpdate     NewFirst     LastNumberHourUpdate     NewLast
  1        7.0                     7a          16.0                   4p
  2        2.0                     2a          22.0                   10p
  3        16.0                    4p          23.0                   11p
```

I would like to conduct this conversion while also keeping in mind I will need to add the newly created hour variable to a date variable, creating a datetime variable.

I have tried the following code but it produces a long error

```
T=12
DF['FirstNumberHourUpdate']=np.where(DF["NewFirst"].str.contains("p"),DF.FirstNumberHour + float(T),DF.FirstNumberHour)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Reading about this error [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796600/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-float-to-str) but according to this, it says I need to convert my NewFirst variable to a float variable; however, if i do that will be able to perform this query based on the "p" condition?

ANSWER:

```
DF["L"] = [12 if "p" in item else 0 for item in DF["NewLast"].astype(str).values]
DF.loc[:, "LastNumberHourUpdate"] = DF.loc[:, "LastNumberHour"].astype(int) + DF.L
```

Comment: Having duplicated column name is not a good idea/practice.

Comment: noted, updated question to reflect your instruction

Comment: Can you add code where you create the dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a code to show how I created the FirstNumberHour variable. All of the other variables imported through excel DF=pd.read_excel('Q:\Data Requests\GB\Schedule.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to add values to a column based on another column content. An approach to solve this could be the following one. I will use an invented dataframe to make it more generic and easier to read.

Base array and dataframe:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, '5p', 6], [7, 8, 9]]`
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

```
   A   B  C
0  1   2  3
1  4  5p  6
2  7   8  9
```

First, create an array with the values that you want to add. List comprehension can be useful here, and be sure to cast your column to `str` before trying to check a character or string presence.

```
b = [12 if "p" in item else 0 for item in df["B"].astype(str).values]
```

Here we would have an output with the values we want to add:

> [0, 12, 0]

Add it to your dataframe using `loc`, to the column that you desire. `:` is used to indicate that we are going to access all the rows, since we have constructed an array to add for all rows in our desired column.

```
df.loc[:, "A"] = df.loc[:, "A"] + b
```

Check your output:

```
    A   B  C
0   1   2  3
1  16  5p  6
2   7   8  9
```

If the last operation with the sum gives you an error about not being able to concatenate, that means that one of the two addends is str. The list isn't, we have constructed it like 12 or 0, which python understands as numeric. To solve it, just cast your column as integer as follows:

```
df.loc[:, "A"] = df.loc[:, "A"].astype(int) + b
```

Take into account that in case there are non numeric values in the column, other problems may arise from this operation.

Also remember to take into account this type change for the column in subsequent operations with it in your code.

Comment: Thanks! The first portion of the code works but when I apply the loc, I get the following error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: It means that one of your addens, the terms that are to the right of the equal operator, is a string and the other one is an integer. Since the list is an int, because we have constructed it that way with our statement `[12 if ...`]`, that means that your column type is str instead of int. Let me update the answer to solve it.

Comment: I now get an error ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer but i think I know why - it's because I have some blank values,which I need to remove.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: I removed all null values and the "non-finite" erroe is gone but now there is a new error:ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3617,) (3719,)

Comment: You should create a new question for it, showing the new error and the code where it happens (as well as involved variables).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211315/discussion-between-raven-and-btc-sources).