# I`m stuck in this code. Always getting an error when I`m trying to execute this code. (I`m beginner in python)

Tags: python, syntax-error

Current Code:

```py
weight_lbs=float(input("How much do you weigh(lbs)? : " ))
weight_kg=float(input("My weight is " + weight_lbs/2.205 + "kg"))
print(weight_kg)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: have you search the error you are getting ?

Comment: Can you tell us the error that you are getting?

Comment: `weight_kg=float(input("My weight is " + str(weight_lbs/2.205) + "kg"))`

Comment: You get an error because you try to concatenate string and float. You may try f-string for the output: `weight_kg=float(input(f"My weight is {weight_lbs/2.205} kg"))`. I am also not sure you need input function in `weight_kg`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796600/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-float-to-str)

Comment: You don't need to ask for user input again the 2nd time and can just print the calculated weight...
    `KILIOGRAM_TO_POUND = 2.205`
    `weight_lbs = float(input('How much do you weigh in lbs?: '))`
    `weight_kg = weight_lbs / KILIOGRAM_TO_POUND`
    `print(f'Your weight is {weight_kg:.2f} kg')`

Comment: @TheWhiteFang I`m getting a Type error: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
weight_lbs = float(input("How much do you weigh(lbs)? : " ))

kg = str(weight_lbs/2.205)

print("My weight is " + kg + "kg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add string with a floating value

So, solution is to convert the floating value to string and then concatenate

```
weight_lbs=float(input("How much do you weigh(lbs)? : " ))
weight_kg=float(input("My weight is " + str(weight_lbs/2.205) + "kg"))
print(weight_kg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to run your code, the following error appears:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

this is because, you are trying to concatenate a string with a number of type float precisely. Concatenation can only occur between strings, so you need to convert this data type and in python you simply do this with str() as follows:

```py
weight_lbs=float(input("How much do you weigh(lbs)? : " ))
weight_kg=float(input("My weight is " + str(weight_lbs/2.205) + "kg"))
print(weight_kg)
```

Comment: If I use float(input("My weight is " + str(weight_lbs/2.205) + "kg")) I`m getting  syntaxError: unmatched `)`

Comment: Try to be sure that you have inserted the parentheses in the right way in your full code. The error tells you that you put an extra one at the end somewhere. If you run the code I posted as an answer it does not give you this problem.